# Capture output port writes and reads

Tags: parallel-port

I have a peripheral that connects to a PC via parallel port, the problem is that most modern laptops don't have a parallel port.

I was able to find a integrated circuit that connects to USB and makes available all the inputs and outputs that I need but unfortunately it is not mapped as a regular parallel port (doesn't have an address associated with it, like 0x278 or 0x378, etc), instead we get access to the inputs and outputs via a DLL.

Is there a way to capture the writes and reads to a port so I can redirect them to the DLL functions? Preferably in a way that works in Windows 7 and 8.